# Autentificación (login) en cakephp 3.x para 2 tablas(models) de usuarios

Tags: login, cakephp, autenticación

Estoy empezando en *Cakephp3* y me ha resultado muy bueno y le he estado sacando a cada componente todo lo que puedo, pero hay un componente que no logro entender del todo. Con el componente de autentificación quiero intentar que se puedan hacer *log* de 2 tablas y 2 usuarios.

Explicando más a detalle, lo que quiero hacer es unos tipos de usuarios de la primera tabla (`a`) crean a los de la segunda tabla (`b`), pero no los puedo tener en la misma tabla por que cuando borras el usuario de la tabla `a` debe borrar los usuarios que pongo en la tabla (`b`) (`'delete' => 'CASCADE'`).

Entonces quiero que ambos usuarios puedan logear por el mismo login que hice.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authorize' => ['Controller'],
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'account',
                'password' => 'password'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Managers',
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
    'authError' => 'Ingrese sus datos',
    'loginRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Managers',
        'action' => 'home'
    ],
    'logoutRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Managers',
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
     'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
]);
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
    'Basic' => ['userModel' => 'Managers'],
    'Form' => ['userModel' => 'Managers']
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

No es posible, tendrías que usar diferentes páginas de inicio de sesión, o un *Dropdown* para poder seleccionar el modelo correcto. La única forma de manejar las dos tablas, es por 2 modelos diferentes, cada uno con su tabla respectiva.

Para usar la misma tabla podrías modificar el método `Delete` del controlador, para que llame a una función del modelo que elimine usuarios con el `parent_id`. Al crear un ***sub-usuario*** le estarías asignando en el formulario un `ParentID` (id del usuario padre).

Controlador Users:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    if ($this->Users->delete($user) && $this->Users->deleteChildUsers($id))
    {
        $this->Flash->success(__('El usuario ha sido eliminado.'));

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

Users Table:

```
function deleteChildUsers($ParentId)
{
    return $this->deleteAll(['parent_id' => $ParentId]);
}
```

Tendrías que tener una tabla como esta:

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parent_id    | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username     | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created      | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```